# Lighter midrule

Tags: tables, color, rules

I have a table that looks like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
A   &   B   \\
\midrule
Q   &   M   \\
W   &   N   \\
E   &   B   \\
R   &   V   \\
T   &   C   \\

Y   &   X   \\
U   &   L   \\
I   &   K   \\
O   &   J   \\
P   &   H   \\

A   &   5   \\
S   &   7   \\
D   &   8   \\
F   &   2   \\
G   &   4   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The code has five-line blocks, which can be made distinguishable in the output with `\midrule`, but I consider that to be too distracting, as would be to number each row. I'd like to have a lighter rule, with tweakable space above and below it. I added some grey lines with Paint to a `\midrule`-less table.

Forcing a color onto `\midrule` with either `\textcolor` or `\color` produces errors, while using `\rule` allows coloring but requires making measurements to get the correct width.

[image: L: Goal, R: <code>\midrule</code> attempt]

Comment: `\specialrule{width}{abovespace}{belowspace}`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\arrayrulecolor{<colour>}` from [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) to change the colour, and `\specialrule{<width>}{<above>}{<below>}` to set a rule of specific dimensions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
  \toprule
  A   &   B   \\
  \midrule
  Q   &   M   \\
  W   &   N   \\
  E   &   B   \\
  R   &   V   \\
  T   &   C   \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black!30}\midrule
  Y   &   X   \\
  U   &   L   \\
  I   &   K   \\
  O   &   J   \\
  P   &   H   \\
 \arrayrulecolor{black!50}\specialrule{3pt}{2\jot}{1pc}
  A   &   5   \\
  S   &   7   \\
  D   &   8   \\
  F   &   2   \\
  G   &   4   \\
  \arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note that the rule colour change is global, so you'll have to reset to `black` if it's been changed before.

Comment: From this answer, I defined `\newcommand{\greyrule}{\arrayrulecolor{black!30}\midrule\arrayrulecolor{black}}` so that I can easily use `\greyrule` within tables.

Answer (score 9):

For colours you have to use `\arrayrulecolor{…}` at the beginning of a row. For the thickness of `\midrules`, you can change the value of `\lightrulewidth` or change the thickness of a specific rule with the optional argument. Demo:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\setlength\lightrulewidth{0.3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B \\
\arrayrulecolor{Grey0!60!RoyalBlue3}\midrule[0.5pt]
Q & M \\
W & N \\
E & B \\
R & V \\
T & C \\
\arrayrulecolor{OrangeRed1! 50}\midrule
Y & X \\
U & L \\
I & K \\
O & J \\
P & H \\
\midrule
A & 5 \\
S & 7 \\
D & 8 \\
F & 2 \\
G & 4 \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]