# Does rulewidth depend on the pdf viewer?

Tags: tex-core, rules

I set rule width like so.

```
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 0.001pt}}
```

It renders just fine in my texStudio viewer, as very very faint lines. But when I open the pdf in an external viewer... I get these really thick standard lines. What's happening?  It also appears other thickness values I've set to  0.001pt get ignored.

Comment: Given an enough zoom level (possibly not available in some viewers, for that width), both viewers will display the exact same width. However if the width of the rule is less than one pixel on your screen, then its appearance depends on the implementation of the viewer and the heuristics it uses to determine how many pixels are coloured, and which colour to apply.

Comment: Thanks. Is there something I can do to make lines faint that's not through thickness settings then? More likely than not the work will be read electronically, not on paper, and I need faint lines...

Comment: Well, at the very end of the process what you see are coloured pixels (and you can't see smaller things because otherwise your pixel would be two pixels, and your screen would double in resolution). What is probably happening under the hood is that the "thick line viewer" is painting a column of pixels black because there is a line there. What TeXStudio's viewer is probably doing is using some shade of grey to emulate the "faintness" of the rule, so I _think_ (based on pure guesswork) that if you use some gray colour for the rule, then you will see a similar effect...

Comment: .001pt isn't faint it is impossibly small.  try something like `{\color[gray]{0.2}\vrule width .4pt}`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks.

Comment: For the remaining rules, I found this helpful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317077/lighter-midrule